# Running flask in cmd but a mistake?

Tags: python, flask

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
```

why?and how can i solve it?
appreciate it!

I tried to ask chat-gpt,but only get me more confused:
This error is reported because the Flask framework is unable to find the project's application. When you start a Flask application using the flask run command, Flask looks for the wsgi.py or app.py file in the current directory to locate the application. If these files do not exist, Flask will not be able to find the application and throws this error.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following:

Make sure that your application files (such as app.py or wsgi.py) are located in the current working directory. If not, copy them to the desired location.

Set the FLASK_APP environment variable to specify the location of your Flask application. For example, from the Windows command line, you can set the FLASK_APP environment variable to app.py with the following command:

Copy
set FLASK_APP=app.py

```
Note: `app.py` is the name of your Flask application file.

If you are using the Flask Blueprint architecture, you need to make sure that you import and register the blueprint in your application file. For example, in the app.py file, you can use the following code to import and register the blueprint:

Copy
from flask import Flask
from my_blueprint import bp

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(bp)
Here my_blueprint is your blueprint object.

If you are using the Flask factory function architecture, you need to make sure that you create and return Flask application objects in your application factory functions. For example, in the factory.py file, you can create and return application objects using the following code:

Copy
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # do something...
    return app
After this, you also need to set the FLASK_APP environment variable to the name of your application's factory function, for example:

Copy
set FLASK_APP=factory:create_app
The factory:create_app here refers to the create_app factory function in the factory.py file.

I hope these solutions will help you to solve the problem.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)
```

Comment: well,I forget to paste my input in cmd,so the whole question is about:C:\Users\86186>flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=11451
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I think the error is self-explanatory.  You need to set the environment variable ```FLASK_APP``` to point to your app.

Comment: Thank you.I solved it.I forget to  execute flask run in the project folder.